# React or express routing with React templating and ExpressJS backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes

I was wondering how to handle a react front-end working with ExpressJS backend. I am searching for good tutorial, but I do not find anything relevant which explain really well the difference between React-Routing (front-side ?) and Express-Routing (back !).

I have an application in react (create with create-app-react), I have some components, a routing with switch, etc. and it works well, I try to run that with Express and I figured out how to do that:

```
// Always return the main index.html, so react-router render the route in the client
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

But right now, I am wondering how can I implement middleware with all of this ? Is the react-routing a mandatory thing ? Can I only use the Express one ? Or maybe a combo (to get some middleware...).

Sorry if it is not really clear, but I am searching for some ressource which can explain everything.

Comment: The react router enables you the ability to render different pages on the client, this means you don't need to send a request to the server to render a new page. If you send a request to the server (by clicking a link), like you do with express, you would have a browser reload on every new page

Comment: So I can do a combo of react and express routing depending on which thing I I would like to handle? (If only client side > react routing || if refresh with server or Middleware things > express routing)

Comment: Yes you can use what you like, depending on your use case. For API Endpoints you could definitely use expressjs. But in React you usually have one index.html (if you use create-react-app). Using Expressjs you would normally end up with multiple files, which is not recommended. React Router allows also server side rendering, it's worth checking out https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement anything other than a catch all route in express like you did already. You can use react-router alone to handle routing on the client side.